# STS 3.6.2 Disappearing context menu items

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, ivyde

So I upgraded to Spring Source Tool Suite 3.6.2, and I've been having a few problems. The current one is now for some projects I get incomplete context menus:

[image]

Some notes:

- It's only for some projects, not all
- The items that are blank vary, sometimes the full menu shows up
- I've tried `STS.exe -clean`
- I've tried deleting the .metadata folder
- I've tried changing the theme
- It appears to correlate with SVN projects where the `Team` menu item never shows up

To elaborate on the last point, all 20 or so of my projects are on SVN. For the ones where the menu seems funky (at least on the 5 or so I tested), when I could get the full menu to show up, the Team menu doesn't. This is even on a fresh STS install without SVN Connectors.

I just tested a new install of STS, and things were working fine until after restarting after an install of IvyDE. Ivy is needed for some of the projects, I haven't analyzed the correlation yet. I will try to remove that and report back.

This is also happening for two other people on my team, with brand new computers (and thus, workspaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was IvyDE. Specifically the 2.2.0.final-201311091524-RELEASE version (takes breath). I'm going to try to find a version that works. My SVN stuff is not causing any problems.

[image]

### Update

I've fixed my issues. I used a development build from the CI trunk build artifact site at: https://builds.apache.org/job/IvyDE-updatesite/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/build/

The versions included were:

- Apache Ivy `2.5.0alpha_20141106222552`
- Apache Ivy Ant Tasks `2.5.0alpha_20141106222552`
- Apache IvyDE `2.3.0beta1-201409280037-hudson-296`
- Apache IvyDE Resolve Visualizer `2.3.0beta1-201409280037-hudson-296` (Optional)

Note that I tried just updating IvyDE to 2.5a, but still had issues. Updating Ivy fixed all my issues so far.

I filed a bug with Apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVYDE-377

Comment: Please let us know. I'm using the latest and it's still a problem. May be Luna specific as I don't recall seeing this in Kepler.

Comment: I tried to install IvyDE into a fresh STS 3.6.2 (on Eclipse 4.4.1) and at least the installation seems to work fine, so there are no immediate conflicts showing up under the hood of the dependencies of the various plugins. You can verify that yourself by opening a console view, switch to "OSGi Host Console", type in "ss" and look for bundles in the "INSTALLED" state. That would indicate a bundle dependency conflict somewhere.

Comment: FYI: most likely this problem is caused by this bug in Eclipse 4.4.1 which caused trouble, amongst others for IvyDE. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122

Comment: From the bug report that @Kris posted, and which is now fixed, these are the instructions:

"The patch is now available from the normal 4.4 update site: 

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/

Note that in no cases (that I know of) will the "check for updates" find this patch, (due to the nature of "root features", etc.) but it should be installable into any project or EPP package that is based on Eclipse Platform 4.4.1. The majority of users simply need to use "Install new software" and pick the category named `Eclipse 4.4.1 patches for bug 445122`."